# Would it be fair to describing a parser generator as a functional language?

Tags: parsers, functional-programming

I'm playing around with the implementation of PEGs and it struct me that the parser generator itself isn't any different than the language it's use to construct. If fact, it has all of the hallmarks of a compiled (pure) functional programming language:

1. It's declarative
2. State is passed around to other functions and after its manipulated it's returned
3. There are no global side effects
4. It generates machine instructions

Is this an accurate assessment?

If so, why don't we present these languages alongside other functional languages?